# Paradoxical result arising regarding velocity

Tags: kinematics, velocity

I was working on a problem that goes like this

> Bob beats Judy by 10 m in a 100-m dash. Bob, claiming to give Judy an
> equal chance, agrees to race her again but to start from 10 m behind the
> starting line. Does this really give Judy an equal chance?( Assuming no acceleration and constant velocity).

After you make some calculations you arise at result that it is not true and Bob still finishes first , I am attaching a [link](https://www.askiitians.com/forums/Mechanics/bob-beats-judy-by-10-m-in-a-100-m-dash-bob-claim_116381.htm) to that.

But I took a different route.

Let us say Bob reaches the finish line after $t_1$ seconds and let the initial point $t$ when race started be 0.

Since the velocity is constant therefore he would have by then covered $ut_1$ metres where $u$ is his velocity.

Let Judy's velocity be $u_j$ then at the point when Bob finished the race she would have covered $u_jt_1$ metre but we know this $10m$ less than what Bob covered i.e. $u_jt_1=ut_1-10$

Now let us consider the second race and let the point where Bob is standing be the origin then similarly as described above after $t_2$ seconds Bob covers $ut_2$ metres Judy covers $ut_2-10$ metres the position of Bob will be $ut$  only since he stands at origin but position of Judy will be her $position_{initial} + ut_2-10$ that is $10+ut_2-10 = ut_2$. Thus we infer that at any point $t_2$ they are at same place. So when Bob finishes the race so does Judy.

What did I do wrong?
Why my answer isn't coming in coherence with the first one?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that check-my-work questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @Stuti That's true, but Mohd is asking about the conceptual errors underlying the method, and that *is* on-topic.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'll take that back, but I think it's largely opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after $t_2$ seconds Bob covers $ut_2$ metres Judy covers $ut_2-10$ metres

This is not true.  Judy will not cover $u_jt_2 - 10$ meters in that time.  For an intuition check, take this to an extreme.  Make Bob an accomplished sprinter, and Judy is actually an infant just learning to crawl (and thus is very slow).  Instead of Bob beating Judy by 10m, let's let him beat her by 99m -- he runs 100m in the time it takes her to crawl 1m.  So Bob increases his run by 99m, to 199m, and they race again.  It should be intuitively clear that, in this extreme scenario Judy doesn't stand a chance.  Intuitively we should see that she should be able to go somewhere around ~2m in the time Bob can go 199m because 199m is very close to 200m. Bob ran almost twice as far in the second race, so we'd expect Judy to crawl almost twice as far (she'll actually get 1.99m, but for intuitive checks, we can just round it a bit)

Let's go back to the original fully grown Judy now, and work through the real numbers.

The mistake here is that $ut_2-10 \text m$ is not derived from any equations of motion, but rather from an intuition as to how the race should have gone.  You wont find any equations in the textbook to support it.

Instead, we can take your correct equation from the first race, $u_jt_1=ut_1-10\text m$ and divide by $t_1$ to get $u_j = u-\frac{10 \text m}{t_1}$.  Now, if we substitute this into $u_jt_2$ to see how far Judy runs in $t_2$ seconds, we get $(u-\frac{10 \text m}{t_1})t_2=ut_2-(10\text m)\frac{t_2}{t_1}$.  This is almost the same as the $ut_2-10 \text{m}$ that you got, except note that we can't just cancel the $t_2$ and the $t_1$ because the times are not the same.

Comment: +1 for the vivid illustration of the baby crawling, which makes the underlying principle so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

> Now let us consider the second race and let the point where Bob is standing be the origin then similarly as described above after $t$ seconds Bob covers $ut$ metres Judy covers $ut−10$ metres

$t\neq t_1$ and so Judy will cover a different distance from what you think it is.

Comment: No , in the second race t carries a different meaning than the first race, I will edit my question be a bit more clear.

Comment: It is still wrong. $ut_2-10$ refers to something wrong.